# Which SVN and Client is smoothest for working on Live Server

Tags: svn

I have a hosting account for my site. I want to install SVN along with a client so that we can provide access and permissions to other people to become a part of us and review the codes( when and where required). Can anyone let me know how this can be done? I have installed Tortoise along with collab, but it can be done through local only.

Anyone assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `... it can be done through local only.`?

Comment: I meant to say that it is running as localhost for a single machine. How can i make it run on Live Server ? Need help on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically source control solution has two parts

1. A code repository on a server
2. Client software to work on the repository resources.

What you have by installing Tortoise SVN on on your machine is completed the second portion.

What remains pending is setting up a repository on server. For this you will have to work with your web-hosting manager to check if they have SVN installed on their servers. If yes, then you will have to setup a repository on that server. See [this article](http://civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps).

Once this is done, you can use tortoise to do day-to-day activities.

Comment: Put questions on stack overflow. People will help.

Comment: Also, i hav seen that post before. But can you kindly tell me how can i install SVN on the server ( and if they are present how can i find it ? ) Awaiting feedback.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. On how to install get in touch with your web-hosting provider.

Comment: Ok, also i'm using tortoise 1.6 along with collab. Shall i use Visual SVN. Will this work ?

Comment: I haven't worked with Visual SVN. TortoiseSVN, I am using it for lst 5 years and my experience is great with it.

Comment: ok, Maheep, tell me one thing. Is Visual SVN and Tortoise complement to each other or they are Substitutes ? I'm confused with it as this is the first time that i am using it.

Comment: No Idea about VisualSVN. browse internet to get more information on this topic. Lets not start a chat session here. Thanks.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to access chat. Still a newbie here